# rxpy: buffer_with_time with a random jitter?

Tags: python, reactivex, rx-py

I am using [buffer_with_time](https://ninmesara.github.io/RxPY/api/operators/buffer.html#rx.Observable.buffer_with_time), it accepts a keyword argument:

```
timespan – Length of each buffer (specified as an integer denoting milliseconds)
```

However, the timestamp is fixed. I want to add a random jitter to it.

If my parallel task was started at the same time, a fixed `timespan=5000` would jam at the same time every five seconds. How to make `timespan` more dynamic, something like 5000±300ms so gradually buffer events would be fired evenly?